# How to keep login state and logout state in android firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, state

I'm creating budgeting application that has login part. Let's say the user is already login so it goes in the HomePage activity. But the user back to the home menu and close the app in the task manager and when the user comes back in the app it must stay login and in HomePage unless the user click the logout it goes back in loginActivity. How I will do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is used to manage login session from firebase its check user login or not....

Checking User Session

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        // User is logged in
    }
```

Sign Out or Log out

```
auth.signOut();

// this listener will be called when there is change in firebase user session
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user == null) {

                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
```

For more information follow this link http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/